# scrlayer-scrpage - chapter on even pages, section on odd pages

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage

I know there are related questions, but I am still not getting it to work.

I have a long document with 3 chapters, and in each chapter, there are sections such as "1.2.3" for Chapter 1, section 2.3.

I need the chapters to appear on even pages, on the right. The section (only the first level, i.e. 1.2) needs to appear odd pages, on the left.

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
\title{Dissertation}
\author{xx}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{float, afterpage, rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, epstopdf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, moreverb, relsize}
\usepackage{eurosym, calc, chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption} %add labelfont={bf} as option to make 'Table 1.x' or 'Figure 3.x' bold (but not rest of caption)
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB02}{fl}
\usepackage{setspace,geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}


\geometry{a4paper, headsep=0.6cm, left=33mm, right=33mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm} %headsep verschiebt die Kopfzeile (Standard ist etwa bei 1cm)



% Kopfzeile anpassen
\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% Default headsepline width = 0.4pt
\automark[subsection]{section}
\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightbotmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightbotmark}}
\ihead{\MakeTextUppercase{\leftmark}}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Subsection}

xxxxxxxx

\clearpage

xxxxxxxxx

\clearpage

xxxxxxxxx

\clearpage

xxxxxxxxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\clearscrheadings 
\clearscrplain 
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} ` give the desired result?

Comment: Yes, I used: \usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% Default headsepline width = 0.4pt
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadings 
\clearscrplain 
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark} 
\cfoot[\thepage]{\pagemark} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                   Is there a way to change "Chapter 1. Test Chapter" to "1. Test Chapter" ?

Comment: `\clearscrheadfoot` is a short version of `\clearscrheadings\clearscrplain`. These three commands are outdated. They should be replaced by `\clearpairofpagestyles` and `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles\clearplainofpairofpagestyles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
```

`\clearpairofpagestyles` replaces the outdated `\clearscrheadfoot`. `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` is a short version of `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`.
If there should be no chapter prefix in header add

```latex
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\enskip}
```

Example without the unrelated stuff:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=0.6cm, left=33mm, right=33mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm,
  headheight=14.5pt% <- added
}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\enskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional remark: You have to clean up your preamble. You load the standard class `book` - so you have to remove the KOMA-Script options `DIV=12`, `listof=totocnumbered` and `bibliography=totoc`. Package `a4wide` is outdated and useless in the example because you are using `geometry`. Do not load packages twice (`graphicx`, `amsfonts`, `eurosym`, `tabularx`, `booktabs`). Package `pgfplots` loads packages `tikz`, `xcolor`, `graphicx`, `rotating` automatically. With an uptodate TeX distribution package `chngcntr` and package `inputenc` with option `utf8` are not needed.

Comment: Is there an easy way to have the page numbers in the header? So left alligned for chapter level pages, and right alligned for section level pages.

Comment: Replace `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` by `\ohead*{\pagemark}`.