# scrlayer-scrpage - chapter on even pages, section on odd pages in scrreprt

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script, scrreprt

I want to have a headings layout as in *Anthony Knapp's Lie Groups*, i.e. I want to have

[image]

the chapter on even, and the current section on odd pages. I'm using the `scrreprt` class and tried using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530308/scrlayer-scrpage-chapter-on-even-pages-section-on-odd-pages):

```
\usepackage[
        automark,
        autooneside=false,
        headsepline,
    ]
    {scrlayer-scrpage}
        \clearpairofpagestyles
        \cfoot*{\pagemark}
        \chead{\headmark}
        \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.\enskip}
```

but this only seems to work in the book class. Also I want to have the page numbers on the bottom but I already go that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the internal command `\Ifthispageodd` and test if the page is even or odd, and then set the running heading as you like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false,% <- if you want to use \leftmark and \rightmark in a one sided document
  headsepline=true
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cohead{\Ifthispageodd{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}


\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using this gives me the chapter name on every page.

Comment: @HannahBloom See updated answer.

Comment: this gives me the error "! Package scrlayer Error: unexpected value to `automark'.See the scrlayer package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \KOMAProcessOptions"

But I found another solution, it works if you use the global option twoside=semi, which gives a onesided  layout while acutally being twoside